# "Right back at you" meaning and usage

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I searched for ***Right back at you*** meaning and saw that it means **you too**, and used in fun, sporty, easy- going manner, when someone compliments you.

I saw an example given :

> A: Nice car!
>    B: Right back at you.

I do not understand this. In this context how can you say **you too** to the person *A* ? Wouldn't it mean that, you are saying "person *A* is also a car" ?

Any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right back at you!

or, more simply,

> Back at you!

or just

> Back atcha!

are used to return expressions of approval.

As you suspect, they mean "you too" in most contexts.

The reason you are having trouble with the example sentence is because it doesn't seem to make much sense—unless both people have nice cars. Do they?

Note: they wouldn't ever mean "person A is also a car" but in all probability person A *does* have a nice car.

Comment: Yes of course, if the other person also have a car, then "right back at you" or "you too " makes sense.
So, if the other person does not have a car, this phrase does not make sense, so in that case I should not say this phrase, right ?

Comment: @Spectra: Pretty much, yes.